# mktemp: invalid option -- - on RHEL5 U3

Tags: linux, makefile, rhel5

I am using the mktemp to create a temp file in Makefile and using this MakeFile on RHEL5 U3 build environment.

```
setuptmp1=`mktemp setup.tmp.1.XXXXXXXX --tmpdir=/tmp` ; \

setuptmp2=`mktemp setup.tmp.2.XXXXXXXX --tmpdir=/tmp` ; \
```

Observed following message in build log.

**mktemp: invalid option -- -**

**Usage: mktemp -V | -dqtu -p prefix template**

What does this mean? Is something wrong in usage of mktemp ?

Comment: have you tried the `$()` method? It's safer, and may handle this better. `setuptmp1="$(mktemp setup.tmp.1.XXXXXX --tmpdir=/tmp)"`

Comment: `mktemp` in rhel5 [is different](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1155729) then in rhel6. Check the man page for correct usage.

Answer (score 1):

The `mktemp` utility has different sets of flags on different systems, depending on the version that ships with that system.  The `mktemp` on OS X is also missing the `--tmpdir` option.

However, all versions of `mktemp` that I can see on my systems honors the `TMPDIR` environment variable when using `-t` (see [the `mktemp` manual](https://www.mktemp.org/manual.html)).  So the following should work for you:

```
export TMPDIR="/tmp"
setuptmp1=$( mktemp -t setup.tmp.1.XXXXXXXX )
setuptmp2=$( mktemp -t setup.tmp.2.XXXXXXXX )
```

Answer (score 0):

According to *[check-kernel-headers: mktemp --tmpdir not available on RedHat RHEL5](https://code.kodo.org.uk/dom/buildroot/commit/53223cbb4e775ce88c036ddbfcca260e23c5739e)* ,

> **`mktemp --tmpdir`** is not available on older Redhat RHEL5 machines. The
>   alternative that has the same behavior is **`'mktemp -t'`**.

There is a related bug-report (no backward compatibility either): RHEL6 `mktemp` uses `-t` to refer to what RHEL5 supported with `-r`: *[Bug 1155729RHEL5 and RHEL6: mktemp -t XXXXXX.pdf: functionality differs](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=1155729)*